# Magento getIdentifier(); always returns "home"

Tags: magento

On every site magento function getIdentifier(); returns "home".

Does anyone have an idea why?
Thanks.

Comment: Against what object and in what file are you calling this method?

Comment: I call this function in the footer.phtml with `$pageTitle = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();`

Comment: Then there's something terribly wrong with your Magento installation.

Comment: installation went as excpected. no errors or similar things, maybe have a look? www.mmagear.ch

Comment: Ok the first thing i can suggest is tun off all extensions, revert to default theme and then check if you still have this issue with identifier.

Comment: i cant easily do that, because the shop is live and i dont have any other ftp to test it. is there not any othe rsolution? someone with the same problem?

Comment: You can at least try the default theme by creating a dummy CMS page and selecting `default/default` on `Design` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivated the footer cache solved it for me